# Cordova CLI build gradle error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/gradle/internal/ToolingRegistryProvider

Tags: apache, cordova, gradle

i follow steps based on cordova installation instruction
[here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html).
but when i want to build a hello project, it gives me following error :

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/gradle/internal/ToolingRegistryProvider**

does anyone knows what's went wrong?

additional info :
*Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0

Android SDK: installed true

Android target: installed Google Inc.:Google APIs:24,Google Inc.:Google APIs (x86 System Image):19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:15,android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-19,android-15,android-14

Gradle: installed D:\gradle\gradle-4.4.1\bin\gradle*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9JFA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kmno, try this in your build.gradle to see if it works. ([Android dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven))

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @chenrui, i already add these lines. but still get same error.

Comment: @kmno, can you post your code somewhere, so that i look further? The info you pasted seems not quite enough.